# $\{c_i\}$ is an infinite set. Is there a function $f(x)$ with $f'(c_i)=0$, $c_i\in (a,b)$ and there are at least $d\in (c_i,c_{i+1})$ $f'(d)\not =0$?

Tags: calculus

Let $\{c_i\}$ be an infinite ordered set where $c_i\in (a,b)$ and $f'(c_i)=0$. Is there a function $f(x)$ such that there are at least one $d\in (c_i,c_{i+1})$ and $f'(d)\not =0$?

In other words, is there a function $f(x)$ in $(a,b)$ with infinitely many isolated stationary points and there are at least one non stationary points between two consecutive stationary points?

Comment: Do you mean that for every $i$ there exists such a $d$, or did you mean that there exists such a $d$ for *some* $i$?

Comment: @nirshahar: For every $i$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: Think about $\sin(1/x)$.

Comment: Thank you very much. Any other examples are welcome. :-)

Comment: @MakeMeSmarterEveryDay For one point of condensation it is a model to obtain examples for any set of $c_i$ by local modifications of the function on $(c_i,c_{i+1})$ of the type $f(x)=g(a+bx)$.